# How to set font size 12 on php printer

Tags: php, printing, pos, php-printer

Good day guys, I need your help to fix my code. Im using client's printer and I need to set the font to 12 because the output is to large. please check the code below

```
    $content .= "This receipt is for inventory purpose only.**";
$printer = ("MYPOS");
$handler = printer_open($printer);
if ($handler) {
    printer_write($handler, $content);
    printer_close($handler);
} else {
    echo "not connected";
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing with PHP - Different font sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546491/printing-with-php-different-font-sizes)

Comment: Depends on the printer. If you're printing raw text to the printer, you'll need to find out what code sequence switches it into and out of 12cpi (that is, if you mean 12cpi rather than 12 point), whether it is using Epson, HP or other codes.